# How to switch a boolean field when there is a change in another field in django?

Tags: python, django, boolean

I'm trying to switch a boolean field (tagged) when there is a change in the `ManyToMany` field(tag). How can i do that?

```
class Tagger(models.Model):
    tagged = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    appName =  models.ForeignKey(AppName,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True)
```

I expect the 'tagged' field to switch to True when there is an input in 'tag'
and vice versa.

Comment: After taking the input, check the variable 'appName'. If it is not null, change state of 'tagged '

Comment: Why on a change. What if tags are removed or changed when there were tags before and after? Also, if you are doing what I think you are doing, the information is redundant and easily queried: `tag__isnull=False` corresponds to `tagged=True` in any query.

Comment: you would typically use signals.

Comment: As @schwobaseggl and bear brown say, never create a field for data that can be easily calculated from existing data in your database. It only creates headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like the simple way is use `property`

```
class Tagger(models.Model):
    appName =  models.ForeignKey(AppName,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    @property
    def tagged(self):
        return bool(self.tag.all())
```

to display the field in the admin dashboard just add it to the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), for example:

```
class TaggerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'tagged')
```

Comment: okay, how can i display this tagged in my listdisplay in admin dahboard?

Comment: list_display = ('tagged','appName')

Comment: sorry, but what i meant was how can i add "tagged" into list_filter.

Comment: [This link explains how to add calculated fields to list_filter](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filtering_calculated_fields.html)

You need to subclass SimpleListFilter.

Comment: It worked, but can i do the same without having to use the property? That is by keeping the boolean field "tagged"..